# Cannot get searchview in actionbar to work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am pretty new to java and android development; and I have been working on an app in which I want an action bar with a `SearchView`. I have looked at the google examples but I can not get it to work. I must be doing something wrong and I'm about to give up on app-development :D I have searched but I have not found anything helpful. Maybe you guys can help me :)

**The problem**: I get the search view to open as it should, but after that nothing happens at all, I've noticed that my *searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName())* returns null. Also my hint that I've given is not displayed in my search box which leads me to believing that maybe the app can't find my searchable.xml? Enough talk :)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
}
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_label">
</searchable>
```

**Androidmanifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.searchapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>           
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>          

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**SearchableActivity.java**

```
package com.example.searchapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        Log.d("Event",query);
    }
}
```

And here is a link to the referred project, I would be eternally grateful if someone was to help me with this!

[Source code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z0amwhu16y1essw/Tjko051u9x/SearchApp.rar)

Comment: menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search) - how did this compile? What is R.id.menu_search?

Comment: how to continue the search in search activity. how to set actionBar   search view again in search activity to search more in the same activity.

Comment: i need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197791/how-to-access-searchview-in-fragment

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Your problem is in your AndroidManifest. I had it almost exactly as you do, because that is what I get following the documentation. But it is unclear or  mistaken.

Watching at the API Demos source I found that the "android.app.searchable" metadata must go in your "results" activity, and in the main activity (or the activity where you place the SearchView) you point to the other one with "android.app.default_searchable".

You can see it in the following file, which is the Manifest from my test project:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- This intent-filter identifies this activity as "searchable" -->

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- This metadata entry provides further configuration details for searches -->
        <!-- that are handled by this activity. -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

It is also important that the hint and label in the searchable.xml are references, and not hardcoded strings.

I hope it solves your problem. It took me all day to figure it out :(

Comment: It totally worked! So it wasn´t just me then I guess :) I'm one happy camper now, thanks Sloy! :)

Comment: This post just saved us - the missing part was `<meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" />`

Comment: It is the Android Dev documentation that is unclear and this answer saved me from implementing lots of code. Thanks!

Comment: _It is also important that the hint and label in the searchable.xml are references, and not hardcoded strings._ .. that fixed my problem. This is very ridiculous bug.

Comment: But i am still messing with implementing search view using `ActionBarSherlock 4.2`, the problem is that it is not starting the `SearchActivity` :(

Comment: Wow - there's another big thing the Android documentation leaves out.

Comment: I can't believe the documentation is actually bugged.. and it looks like it is

Comment: I had the same problem and figured out what to do. It took me longer than I expected since the official doc has several mistakes. It has been asked multiple times in StackOverflow–I found at least 5 posts asking the same question. I flagged them as duplicates to this one. I also [wrote a blog](http://clint.logdown.com/posts/208273-android-unnecessarily-hard-to-get-started) to summarize what I learnt. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to add two search widget in the same action bar of an activity ?

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197791/how-to-access-searchview-in-fragment

Comment: This solves the problem but the search icon in the keypad is replaced by an arrow now. How to get it back?

Comment: I can use hardcoded string as label without any problem.

Comment: Thanks bro. It saves me lots of time.... Android Documentation is nothing clear about this.

Answer (score 83):

Android guides explicitly says:

```
// Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Which is in your case NOT TRUE. Because you don't want to search in MainActivity but in SearchableActivity. That means you should use this ComponentName instead of getComponentName() method:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));
```

Comment: I did the cut'n'paste and did not realize the docs said this. Thanks!

Comment: thaks! It's really the mistake I made

Comment: help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197791/how-to-access-searchview-in-fragment

Comment: This documentation catch also got me. Thank you for help, this advice works great with Xamarin, the only change is that you have to use following C# code `var componentName = new ComponentName(this,  Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(SearchView)))`

Comment: Thanks this really help me a lot. I should add though in my case I have to also add searchable meta in my destination activity manifest in addition with this answer or otherwise it won't launch.

Comment: This solves the problem but the search icon in the keypad is replaced by an arrow now. How to get it back?

Answer (score 12):

Also it seems that both the android:hint and android:label attributes **MUST** be references to strings in strings.xml.  Being lazy and hardcoding the string values doesn't seem to work at all :)

i.e. Don't do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="Search for something..."
    android:label="My App">
</searchable>
```

But definitely do (as the OP correctly did):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_label">
</searchable>
```

Comment: Is this a bug or is this some specific technological restriction? To me, it seems to be a bug (it isn't mentioned in documentation that you can't use hardcoded strings).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I wasted 2 days before figuring this out.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Android Studio,

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

part may not work.

write full package name like

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="com.example.test.SearchActivity" />
```

Comment: No this should not be an issue. I am using Android Studio (version 0.8.1) and it works fine with `.SearchActivity`.

Comment: This solve my problem, with android studio 2.3.3 and build tools 25.0.2

Answer (score 7):

be careful with "xml/searchable.xml".
If you made HARD CODE with `android:hint` and `android:label`.It will not work. Haha
Should be :

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="@string/app_name"
android:label="@string/search_lb"
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

Comment: so weird. is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

There's actually no need use the "missing part" as described in the answers above. This method(using a `SearchView`) works exactly as the official docs say till [Using the Search widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget). Here a slight modification needs to made as follows:

Properties in a `SearchableInfo` are used to display labels, hints, suggestions, create intents for launching search results screens and controlling other affordances such as a voice button([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setSearchableInfo%28android.app.SearchableInfo%29)).

Thus, the `SearchableInfo` object we pass to the `SearchView.setSearchableInfo(SearchableInfo s)` must contain proper references to the target activity which should be displayed to show the search results. This is done by manually passing the `ComponentName` of our target activity. One constructor for creating a `ComponentName` is

```
public ComponentName (String pkg, String cls)
```

`pkg` and `cls` are package names and class names of the target activity to be launched for displaying search results. Note that:

`pkg` must point to the root package name of your project and,

`cls` must be a fully qualified name of the class(i.e. the entire thing)

e.g.:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
String pkg = "com.example.musicapp"
String cls = "com.example.musicapp.search.SearchActivity"
ComponentName mycomponent = new ComponentName(pkg,cls);       
SearchManager searchManager =(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mycomponent));
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);   //if using on actionbar
return true;
}
```

Depending on your requirements take a look at the other `ComponentName` constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `searchables.xml` file is in the correct location (i.e, in your `res/xml/` folder) and that the same file does not contain any errors - otherwise you will find that `(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE).getSearchableInfo(componentName)` will return null, breaking your search functionality.

(Also, ensure you set `componentName` in the appropriate manner, because the example shown in the Android guide is for only when you are making searches and displaying searches in the same Activity.)

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue adding search intent filter like this to searchable activity:

```
   <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Double check if the corresponding entry(ie search_hint and app_label) is present in values/strings.xml

eg

```
      <string name="app_label">FunApp</string>
      <string name="search_hint">Caps Off</string>
```

Comment: he is actually not incorrect just not explaining it enough, see solution below.