# Search widget on action bar doesn't trigger my search activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-searchmanager

I'm developing search widget interface based on official tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

**Problem:** My SearchableActivity doesn't get triggered when I enter my query and press Ok/enter.

*Manifest for SearchableActivity:*

```
<activity android:name="SearchableActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

*xml/searchable.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="Search" android:label="@string/app_name" >
</searchable>
```

*Main activity lifecycle method which adds icons to the action bar (works fine):*

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    // Do not iconify the widget;expand it by default
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

*SearchableActivity.java*

```
public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("MY", "search activity triggered");
   }

}
```

**Note:** The search widget appear on the action bar and I can insert data, but pressing the OK/Enter doesn't take me to the SearchableActivity (doesn't trigger onCreate of the SearchableActivity).

Am I missing something or is the official tutorial flawed?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Problem solved: the tutorial seems to missing one important part: `<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".MySearchActivityName" />` has to be added inside `<application>` tags in manifest to get the search widget working correctly.

**EDIT**- Also a hint to solving a problem when the actionbar search is not triggered on data posting (no error given whatsoever and documentations hasn't got a word about this limitation): in searchable.xml file android:hint and android:label attributes **MUST** be references to strings in strings.xml. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735869/797321)

Comment: I can't at the moment due some kind of limit (tomorrow i'll be able to accept it).

Comment: I had a similar problem. You can put the <meta-data> in the main activity, and it will still work. Just a FYI.

Comment: @IndrekKõue you saved my life i'm stuck on this for almost 5hrs

Comment: Thanks! This could've taken a long time to figure out :)

Comment: I have a problem. While this solution works, it replaces the search key in the keypad with an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onOptionsItemSelected` and probably `onSearchRequested` in your activity.

Comment: I'm using [Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget) not [Search Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#InvokingTheSearchDialog)

Comment: I don't have it overriden, the search widget tutorial doesn't state that it needs to be overriden. Also this part seems to be working (the search dialog opens when i tap the search icon on the action bar and I can enter and delete text).

Comment: You mention search dialog appearing, it should not in case of a widget, the widget is built into the action bar, so what's the case?

Comment: Sorry my bad, by dialog I meant the search widget on the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

If "xml/searchable.xml" file is not correctly formatted (things such as "searchable" tag not in all lower case), there is no error message returned during execution and the "SearchableActivity" doesn't get invoked.