# searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()) returns null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu, searchable, searchview

I've followed [this Android guide](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) in order to add a search bar to an activity. The setup looks like this:

res/menu/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

res/xml/searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

Activity entry in manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="de.ivu.realtime.app.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="de.ivu.realtime.app.activity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

and the code in MainActivity:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
    }

    return true;
```

The call to `searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());` always returns `null`. I've seen this in other questions on stackoverflow, however, none of the solutions presented there seem to apply to my case.

- the menu XML has a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header
- the searchable XML has no hard-coded strings
- renaming the menu item does not work
- cleaning and rebuilding does not do the trick either

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get searchview in actionbar to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work)

Comment: Thank you for the summary of possible sources of errors! I had hard coded strings in searchable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add it to the activity where you've put your SearchView

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".activity_that_handles_the_search" />

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `SearchView` is in the `ActionBar` (see updated question). Since the `MainActivity` has the resources to provide search results, I've added your code to the `MainActivity`-section of the manifest. Still, `searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());` returns `null`.

Comment: Updated the answer. Try to apply yet another the intent-filter as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Using this other guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html, I just figured this out, too :-).

Comment: This code goes in the manifest, in case somebody is wondering.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was my mistake during integration with ActionBarSherlock. In this case `android:actionViewClass` should be `com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView` instead of `android.widget.SearchView`. I know this sounds dumb, but I spent 20 minutes trying to figure out why `searchView` is `null` in my code that is similar to yours.

Comment: My issue was the other way around. I had integrated ActionBarSherlock and this was removed in an app update. com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView needed to be removed and replaced with android.widget.SearchView

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

With:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

Because `app` is often used if you are using support library.