# Trouble setting up search view in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-menu, android-search

I am following the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) on how to set up the UI to use the search view in android. I have literally copied and pasted from them and I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

**Stacktrace**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
    at com.hb.birthpay.activity.FindFriendActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(FindFriendActivity.java:75)
```

**searchable.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:hint="Search people" />
```

**fragment_find_friend_menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
          app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

**FindFriendActivity.java**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_find_friend_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

What is causing the nullPointerexception and how do I fix it?

Comment: Found a duplicate, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912003/searchmanager-getsearchableinfogetcomponentname-returns-null)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing getComponentName() with (this, YourActivity.class)

Comment: getSearchableInfo(ComponentName componentName) does not take in (this, YourActivity.class) as parameters.