# Cannot able to make SearchActivity to start

Tags: android, android-intent, searchview

I try to make SearchView in action bar to start a SearchResultsActivity which is registered to handle ACTION_SEARCH. I do all required steps but still didn't work!

Here's the code:

#### 1. Search View menu item: (menu/main.xml)

> ```
> <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item
>             android:id="@+id/search_action"
>             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
>             android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
>             android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
>             />
> </menu>
> ```

#### 2. Searchable configuration (xml/searchable.xml):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>
> <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:label="@string/app_name"
>             android:hint="@string/search_hint"/>
> ```

#### 2.1 adding Searchable configuration link to MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml:

> ```
> <activity
>         android:name="com.me.searchonpre3.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>     </intent-filter>
>
>     <meta-data
>             android:name="android.app.searchable"
>             android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
> </activity>
> ```

#### 3. Bind the Search View menu item with the search configuration (MainActivity.java):

> ```
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
>
>         SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_action).getActionView();
>         SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
>
>         if (searchView != null) {
>             searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
>         }
>     }
>
>     return true;
> }
> ```

#### 4. add new Activity "SearchResultsActivity" and mark it to handle SEARCH_ACTIONs:

> public class SearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {
>
> ```
>     public static final String TAG = SearchResultsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>         Log.i(TAG, "In SearchResult OnCreate");
>
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
>
>         this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
>                 new String[]{"Product1", "Product2"}));
>     }
> }
> ```

AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.me.searchonpre3.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

All the above settings and the SearchResultsActivity is not started when press the Search keyboard icon.

What else Should I do???

Note: When I add a setOnQueryTextListener, the callbacks being called on the MainActivity class.

Comment: Use `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` to avoid the SDK check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android tutorials are misleading.

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206#11704661