# When configuring an Android search widget, what do you do if the the current activity is not the searchable activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am considering decoupling my search activity from the main activity but am stalled. The example below "Assumes current activity is the searchable activity".

How do you proceed if the current activity is **not** the searchable activity? What do I replace `getComponentName()` with?

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the options menu from XML
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

  // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
  // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
  searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
  searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

  return true;
}
```

Comment: See Sloy's answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work
hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is really late but I was having same problem and solution is to NOT use `getComponentName()`

Instead you should use:

```
// Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OWmnYPX1uc At: 3:50