# Receive search from Google Now

Tags: android, search, android-intent, android-searchmanager, google-now

So I tried to implement this - [The fastest route between voice search and your app](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html)

What i have so far is...

In manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In MainActivity:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        editText.setText(query);
```

}

If I type my app name in Google Now, the app is shown. If I open it nothing happens, so I didn't receive the search term (the app name).

How do I implement like how the post has described "Ok Google, search pizza on MyApp"?

Comment: Did you voice search 'ok google, search QUERY on MyApp'? Just typing the name of your app doesn't trigger this functionality.

Comment: Oh can't it be "MyApp QUERY" ?

Comment: @ArjunU. did this worked for you..I tried the same thing and its working perfectly using adb command but it did not worked with google now search.Will it work only after making it live...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html), queries are in the format:

> Ok Google, search **pizza** on Eat24
>
> Ok Google, search for **hotels in Maui** on TripAdvisor

You'll note the bolded portion is the search term your app receives when a successful voice search in the correct format is sent to your app.

Comment: This is not working for me. I have triple-checked everything, but just can't get this search query delivered to my app. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Well... looks like the app needs to be published on Play Store:
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/afSRdDQiy1N - look for comments by Jarek Wilkiewicz. Going to try this next.

Comment: @Chaitanya it worked for me. No need to publish app in the store. Do you have Google now on your phone?

Comment: @Chaitanya: You need to add some meta data in the manifest as per this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work . For some reason, it's not clear in the Android dev documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the way we check for Intent also may be different. Only this worked for me. As the intent mentioned in the documentation is this.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())
        || "com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    externalQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    //String xquery = query;
}
```

Comment: Putting 'com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION".equals(intent.getAction())' is really not nice. Much better would be 'SearchIntents.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())'