# Android How to connect OK Google voice queries to my app

Tags: android

First of fall sorry for my weak english i want to open my app by "Ok google" with search query. But not Open my app With "Ok Google". I get stuck in it. So suggest me where i wrong

> But Open My App When I try to say open in "Ok Google" with "Open App
>   Name" that time open my app

So please help me thanks for advance

Following my code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

And In Java File

```
 String query = "";
 if (getIntent().getAction() != null &&
          getIntent().getAction().equals("com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION) {
 query = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

}
```

Comment: Check this - [Receive search from Google Now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26718384/6244429)

Comment: Tx for Your Valuable Response But This is not working i  have performed all my side

Comment: Doe's i need to publish app in the store?

Comment: publish app - bro i am not sure

Comment: Ohk bro no problem

Comment: Following code is working some devices  but not work all devices. so what can do work for all devices? '  if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())
                || "com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.d(TAG,"Data---->" + query);
            getDataFromUser(query);'

Comment: @Rahul you do not need to publish the app for voice commands to work source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26718384/1441732