# SearchView doesn't appear in Toolbar - Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have in the following Activity this Toolbar:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_select_currency"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Also the menu is declared in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_currency"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

In the activity I call:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.currency_selector_options_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

private void initActionBar() {
    // Initialize the Toolbar( this is the new ActionBar in Lollipop)
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_select_currency);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.select_currency));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Now my issue is that I do not get the SearchView like in normal ActionBar, what I get is a normal menu. How can I get a normal SearchView ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get searchview in actionbar to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your app namespace:

```
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

myapp:showAsAction="always"
```

**Explanation:**
Since you are using a support library for old android versions and it is not included into the sdk, the `android` namespace doesn't contains the `showAsAction` attribute, which is rather contained into the support library you linked to your project, so to reach the attribute you must use your app namespace

Comment: Thank sir. This worked for me. It would be really helpful if you could explain to me what that custom namespace does and why didnt it work with 'android' ?