# I need to start activity using my SearchView widget on my actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I need to start up my activity `SearchResultsActivity` when the user presses enter on the [Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget). I already have my `onSearchRequested` function being called indirectly whenever I click on my `menu_search` which looks like this.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always" />
```

Whenever I enter query and then enter/search nothing happens. I have set up my manifest file as below:

```
<!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.default.searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <!-- Search Results Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/search_results_activity_title">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Main activity is where I perform the search and SearchResultsActivity receives my search query. I am not concerned about this at the moment. I just want a search to open up my SearchResultsActivity. I have tried a couple of tips like overriding my onOptionsItemSelected

```
case R.id.menu_search:
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchResultsActivity.class);;
            startActivity(searchIntent);
            break;
```

this still does not call my search activity. I have also associated searchable configuration with the SearchView on the onCreateOptionsMenu.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Adding this code returns a `java.lang.ClassCastException`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
        at com.nauv.jambomall.ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:205)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2578)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:277)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:84)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:251)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1089)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:126)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: you can find good example here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work/15735869#15735869

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you chose the wrong import, You should import

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
```

instead of

```
import android.widget.SearchView;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! That helped me solve my `java.lang.ClassCastException` but still search does not open. my results activity.

Comment: Please share code and error logs..that will help me to solve the issues.

Comment: Right now I do not get any errors. What other part of the code would be helpful to solve this?

Comment: share your full code and tell me where you are facing problem....then only i can solve your code

Comment: Set it as an answer to your question... because first you faced `classcast exception` that is solved by my answer..so make it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to fix this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25499711/3128638) answer here.
Previously by using

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

I was assuming current activity is the searchable activity. All I had to do is add this code

```
ComponentName sa = new ComponentName(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
```

which then set my searchable activity to `SearchResultsActivity`